# Change switch statements to two or more functions, each

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

For the 3 switch statements, I am to replace each switch statement with two or more function calls. This is to replace an "incomplete" in my beginning C++ class last semester so that I can get a loan and I've got no idea where to start.

I tried quite literally taking the switch statements and putting them into their own functions, of the switch statements themselves only, and, of course, that created numerous syntax errors (e.g. counter, random_number). I've no idea how to do it, how to return proper values to `main()`  and get the program to communicate with other parts of the program (e.g. variables defined/initialized in main). As one can see, I'm just pretty lost here and would like some guidance toward figuring this out. I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, just some guidance (my knowledge on C++ is limited and there are time constraints).

```
// random.cpp : Defines entry point for the console application.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

//random number generator prototypes
void randomize(void);
void randomize(int seed);
int random(void);
int random(int upper_bound);
int random(int upper_bound, int lower_bound);

int main()
{
int upper_bound = 999;
int lower_bound = 100;
int n_random_numbers = 1000;

randomize();

int counter_0 = 0;
int counter_1 = 0;
int counter_2 = 0;
int counter_3 = 0;
int counter_4 = 0;
int counter_5 = 0;
int counter_6 = 0;
int counter_7 = 0;
int counter_8 = 0;
int counter_9 = 0;

for(int counter = 1; counter <= n_random_numbers; counter++)
{
    int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);
    int digit_1 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_1)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }
    int digit_2 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_2)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }

    int digit_3 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_3)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }

}
cout << "0 occurs " << counter_0 << " times" << endl;
cout << "1 occurs " << counter_1 << " times" << endl;
cout << "2 occurs " << counter_2 << " times" << endl;
cout << "3 occurs " << counter_3 << " times" << endl;
cout << "4 occurs " << counter_4 << " times" << endl;
cout << "5 occurs " << counter_5 << " times" << endl;
cout << "6 occurs " << counter_6 << " times" << endl;
cout << "7 occurs " << counter_7 << " times" << endl;
cout << "8 occurs " << counter_8 << " times" << endl;
cout << "9 occurs " << counter_9 << " times" << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
}

//random number generators
void randomize(void)
{
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
}

void randomize(int seed)
{
srand(unsigned(seed));
}

int random(void)
{
return rand();
}

int random(int upper_bound)
{
return rand() % (upper_bound + 1);
}

int random(int upper_bound, int lower_bound)
{
    if(upper_bound < lower_bound)
        {
    int t = upper_bound;
    upper_bound = lower_bound;
    lower_bound = t;
        }
int range = upper_bound - lower_bound + 1;
int number = rand() % range + lower_bound;
return number;
}
```

I added these functions, to see if it would work (Figure 1.1)
(I added `counter`, `upper_bound`, `lower_bound`, `n_random_numbers` because I couldn't figure out how to have the function read those variables from `main()`. I tried making them into a function, calling them in main, and calling them in my created functions, but that definitely didn't work. These added functions replace the switches in the original with function calls (see: Figure 1.2). It compiles, but the output returns that "0 occurs 0 times, 1 occurs 0 times, etc."

FIGURE 1.1

```
int switch1 (int switch_1)
{
int upper_bound = 999;
int lower_bound = 100;
int n_random_numbers = 1000;
int counter = 0;

randomize();

int counter_0 = 0;
int counter_1 = 0;
int counter_2 = 0;
int counter_3 = 0;
int counter_4 = 0;
int counter_5 = 0;
int counter_6 = 0;
int counter_7 = 0;
int counter_8 = 0;
int counter_9 = 0;

int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);

int digit_1 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_1)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }

}

int switch2 (int switch_2)
{
int upper_bound = 999;
int lower_bound = 100;
int n_random_numbers = 1000;
int counter = 0;

randomize();

int counter_0 = 0;
int counter_1 = 0;
int counter_2 = 0;
int counter_3 = 0;
int counter_4 = 0;
int counter_5 = 0;
int counter_6 = 0;
int counter_7 = 0;
int counter_8 = 0;
int counter_9 = 0;

int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);

int digit_2 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_2)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }

}

int switch3 (int switch_3)
{
int upper_bound = 999;
int lower_bound = 100;
int n_random_numbers = 1000;
int counter = 0;

randomize();

int counter_0 = 0;
int counter_1 = 0;
int counter_2 = 0;
int counter_3 = 0;
int counter_4 = 0;
int counter_5 = 0;
int counter_6 = 0;
int counter_7 = 0;
int counter_8 = 0;
int counter_9 = 0;

int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);

int digit_3 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    switch(digit_3)
    {
        case 0:
            counter_0++;
            break;
        case 1:
            counter_1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            counter_2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            counter_3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            counter_4++;
            break;
        case 5:
            counter_5++;
            break;
        case 6:
            counter_6++;
            break;
        case 7:
            counter_7++;
            break;
        case 8:
            counter_8++;
            break;
        case 9:
            counter_9++;
            break;
    }

}
```

FIGURE 1.2

```
for(int counter = 1; counter <= n_random_numbers; counter++)
{
    int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);
    int digit_1 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    int digit_2 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    int digit_3 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;

switch1 (digit_1);
switch2 (digit_2);
switch3 (digit_3);

}
```

Comment: You should read a good C++ book and learn about arrays, vectors, and collections in general. There are much better ways of doing whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Mat - I'm sure there are better ways of doing this assignment, but the assignment was specifically to "replace each switch statement with two or more function calls." That is why I am proposing the question in such a way.

Comment: If you're going to post an assignment for us to do for you, you could at least post the full text of the requirements, not just the repeated "replace each switch statement with two or more function calls," phrase.

Comment: @NicolBolas - This is the **precise** text of the requirements: "The solution to the second problem of the second test, test2p2solution.cpp, contains 3 switch statements. Replace each switch statement with two or more function calls. You must write the functions. Your program and the original program must, given the same input, produce the same output." I thought that the rest could be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

No switch needed:

```
int counters[10] = {};

for(int counter = 1; counter <= n_random_numbers; counter++)
{
    int random_number = random(upper_bound, lower_bound);
    int digit_1 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    ++counters[digit_1];

    int digit_2 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    ++counters[digit_2];

    int digit_3 = random_number % 10; random_number = random_number / 10;
    ++counters[digit_3];
}
```

Comment: While your solution is very clean and a much better way of programming, I'm sure, the assignment was specifically to "replace each switch statement with two or more function calls," as defined by the professor's instructions (silly, I know). Thank you, though.

Comment: "replace each switch statement with two or more function calls", doesn't rly make much sense...

Comment: The instructions seemed odd to me, too. Take the array and `for` statement you have above, how would one place that into a function? What would you return to the program? And how would the `random(upper_bound, lower_bound)` function be read within the function? Can you call a function within a function?

Comment: Yes, you can call a function within a function, `main` is a function and you are calling other functions within it.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Went right over my head. Well, I tried to put `int upper_bound = 999;
int lower_bound = 100;
int n_random_numbers = 1000;` in a function, call that in main, and call that in functions I made for the switch statements, and it didn't read any variables from that, providing syntax errors. I'm updating the original post with what I tried output).